# How can a value in column B be set more directly at the height of the rows of the selections and the next row be activated?

Tags: arrays, list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

[image]

The columns C to K are hidden. The first row is the header row. The K column contains the following formula in every cell starting with K2.

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("$A"&ROW())),ROW(),"")
```

This allows to detect rows that are not hidden by filter or user. The relevant A cell is located in the row of the K cell. If something is contained, the row number is displayed.
The following function checks whether a value in K occurs in the rows of the selected cells. If so, an x is set in column B. It does not work if a complete row is selected. The code is probably complicated. How can it be simplified without reducing the execution time (1 to 3 seconds)? Maybe it is possible to reduce executions by not storing a value for each selected, non-contiguous cell, but by using a more direct way, so that it works even if a complete row is selected.

Then, in column A, the next non-hidden cell one row below the lowest selection is to be activated (A166). The following code shortly activates A84, which nevertheless results in a suitable shift.

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var list = s.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var ranges = [];
  var ranges2 = [];
  var exp = new RegExp(/[a-z]+/gi);
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var range = list[i].getA1Notation();
    var range = range.replace(exp, 'K');
    var values = s.getRange(range).getValues();
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < values.length; i2++) {
      if (/\S/.test(values[i2])) {
        ranges.push('B'+values[i2]);
        ranges2.push(values[i2]);
      }
    }
  }
  s.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
  var shifting = 'A' + (Math.max(...ranges2) + 1);
  s.getRange(shifting).activate();
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue of your script and your goal. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and goal?

Comment: The code inserts an x in column B in the rows containing a selection, then shortly activates A84 and finally A166, because it is hidden in the above case. How can the code reach the mentioned goal with fewer commands in a more direct way? Maybe it is a bit more indirect and gets by with fewer commands.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about what you want to do. I deeply apologize for this. At first, I would like to correctly understand about your current issue. As the next step, I would like to understand about your goal. So can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By the way, about `It does not work if a complete row is selected.`, in this case, where cells are selected?

Comment: For example, if there are selected cells in rows 2, 4 and 6, an x is set in B2, B4 and B6 if the rows are not hidden according to the K cell. That's the goal. However, if a complete row is selected at any position, the range for setValue() is not found.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- In your goal, you want to put the value of `x` to the column "B" when the rows are selected.
- Even when the entire rows are selected, you want to run the script.

  - You want to ignore the hidden rows.
  - In your current issue, when the entire rows are selected, an error occurs.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I would like to retrieve the row index from the selected ranges. In your current script, the A1Notation is used. By this, when the entire row is used, the column letter is not included. So the error occurs.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var list = s.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var values = s.getRange("K1:K" + s.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var selectedRows = list.reduce((ar, r) => {
    var row = r.getRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < r.getNumRows(); i++) {
      var rowPosition = row + i;
      if (!s.isRowHiddenByUser(rowPosition)) ar.push(rowPosition);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var ranges = selectedRows.reduce((ar, r) => {
    if (values[r - 1][0].toString() != "") ar.push("B" + r);  // or  ar.push("B" + values[r - 1][0]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (ranges.length > 0) {  // Modified
    s.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
    s.getRange(`A${Math.max(...selectedRows) + 1}`).activate();
  }
}
```

- In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved from the column "K". Then, the range list is created using it. By this, I think that the process cost will be a bit reduced.

#### Note:

- Please use this script with V8.

#### References:

- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [isRowHiddenByUser(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition)

Comment: It works great. Thank you. The only thing missing is the activation of the next cell below the lowest selection in column A after setValue().

Comment: @user8652270 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `The only thing missing is the activation of the next cell below the lowest selection in column A after setValue().`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Sometimes the wrong cell is activated. It should follow the scheme `Math.max(..ranges2) + 1`. Of the different selections, the highest row number should be used to activate the cell one row below, if available.

Comment: @user8652270 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. Now I could understand about your situation. In that case, please modify ``s.getRange(`A${selectedRows.pop() + 1}`).activate();`` to ``s.getRange(`A${Math.max(...selectedRows) + 1}`).activate();`` and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

A completely selected row contains no letters.

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var list = s.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var ranges = [];
  var ranges2 = [];
  var exp = new RegExp(/[a-z]+/gi);
  var exp2 = new RegExp(/(\d+)/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var range = list[i].getA1Notation();
    if (!exp.test(range)) {
      var range = range.replace(exp2, 'K$1');
    }
    else {
      var range = range.replace(exp, 'K');
    }
    var values = s.getRange(range).getValues();
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < values.length; i2++) {
      if (/\S/.test(values[i2])) {
        ranges.push('B'+values[i2]);
        ranges2.push(values[i2]);
      }
    }
  }
  s.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
  var shifting = 'A' + (Math.max(...ranges2) + 1);
  s.getRange(shifting).activate();
}
```